# Asp.NET Core 3.1 RazorPages Localization SEO-friendly URLs

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, localization, razor-pages

I have done a lot of research on the above problem, but I can't find the correct solution to fix my problem. Let me explain, I am writing an application using RazorPages with .Net Core 3.1 which is multilingual, I would like it to behave like most sites that use SEO-friendly URLs with localization, example:

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/
https://www.microsoft.com/it-it/windows/

in such a way that I have a culture parameter in the URI path and use it to display my page in the correct language.

I tried to add this in Startup:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.Configure<RequestLocalizationOptions>(options =>
    {
        var supportedCultures = new[]
        {
            new CultureInfo("en"),
            new CultureInfo("de"),
            new CultureInfo("fr"),
            new CultureInfo("es"),
            new CultureInfo("ru"),
            new CultureInfo("ja"),
            new CultureInfo("ar"),
            new CultureInfo("zh"),
            new CultureInfo("en-GB")
        };
        options.DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture("en-GB");
        options.SupportedCultures = supportedCultures;
        options.SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures;
        options.RequestCultureProviders.Insert(0, new RouteDataRequestCultureProvider(){ Options = options});
    });


    services.AddLocalization(options => options.ResourcesPath = "Resources");

    services.AddRazorPages(options =>
    {
        options.Conventions.Add(new CultureTemplatePageRouteModelConvention());
    })
    .AddViewLocalization();
}
```

where CultureTemplatePageRouteModelConvention is:

```
public class CultureTemplatePageRouteModelConvention : IPageRouteModelConvention
{
    public void Apply(PageRouteModel model)
    {
        var selectorCount = model.Selectors.Count;

        for (var i = 0; i < selectorCount; i++)
        {
            var selector = model.Selectors[i];

            model.Selectors.Add(new SelectorModel
            {
                AttributeRouteModel = new AttributeRouteModel
                {
                    Order = -1,
                    Template = AttributeRouteModel.CombineTemplates("{culture?}",
                        selector.AttributeRouteModel.Template),
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

and then add middlewares:

```
.....
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();
var localizationOptions = app.ApplicationServices.GetService<IOptions<RequestLocalizationOptions>>().Value;
app.UseRequestLocalization(localizationOptions);

app.UseAuthorization();

app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapRazorPages();
});
```

But nothing seems to work.
Do you have any solution to this problem? if not, how can I achieve my goal?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This is what I do in my projects and it works for me. Add the following code in the ConfigureServices of the Startup.cs file:

```
services.AddRazorPages().AddRazorPagesOptions(options =>
{
    //options.Conventions.AuthorizeFolder("/Account/Manage");
    //options.Conventions.AuthorizePage("/Account/Logout");
    options.Conventions.AddFolderRouteModelConvention("/", model =>
    {
        foreach (var selector in model.Selectors)
        {
            var attributeRouteModel = selector.AttributeRouteModel;
            attributeRouteModel.Template = AttributeRouteModel.CombineTemplates("{lang=en-US}", attributeRouteModel.Template);
        }
    });
});

IList<CultureInfo> supportedCultures = new List<CultureInfo>
{
    new CultureInfo("en-US"),
    new CultureInfo("el-GR"),
};

var MyOptions = new RequestLocalizationOptions()
{
    DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture(culture: "en-US", uiCulture: "en-US"),
    SupportedCultures = supportedCultures,
    SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures
};
MyOptions.RequestCultureProviders = new[]
{
        new RouteDataRequestCultureProvider() { RouteDataStringKey = "lang", Options = MyOptions }
};

services.AddSingleton(MyOptions);
```

Generate the following class:

```
public class LocalizationPipeline
{
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, RequestLocalizationOptions options)
    {
        app.UseRequestLocalization(options);
    }
}
```

Now over your razor pages class add the following attribute:

```
[MiddlewareFilter(typeof(LocalizationPipeline))]
public class ExampleModel : PageModel
{
```